# How can I disable automatic scrolling of UITableView when swiping with VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a tableview with each cell containing a collectionView (scrolling disabled). When swiping left or right with VoiceOver, the focus moves in unexpected ways. I want to prevent VoiceOver from scrolling the tableview so I can implement custom scrolling behavior.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and would like to know a solution, too. Might be the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603917/how-can-i-make-a-uitableview-with-big-header-voiceover-compatible

Comment: Would you mind describing the custom scrolling behavior you want to implement, please?